# easyEDA simulation not working

Tags: circuit-design, simulation

I tried with 5V to turn on a status LED and a lamp/a 5V pump with two NPN transistors. Ofc at first as simulation. I'm new to simulations so maybe I'm missing something.

In easyEDA it does not turn on the bulb/pump-fake:
[image]

But in two other simulation software everything works like a charm:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong in easyEDA? Would be very hard if I can't trust that software to do my PCBs later...

So the overall question: Am I the error, or easyEDA?

Thanks for your help!

---

Changed the bulb with an resistor:
[image]

Comment: Are those symbols accompanied by their own models or subcircuits? Because, if they're only "cosmetic" (e.g. for PCB) then chances are that they simply cannot simulate.

Comment: I used all items directly from easyEDA without any custom content or something else if you mean that. easyEDA has the "simulation mode" where this light bulb is added for simulations. If I add it directly between VCC and GND it turns on when I hit "play"

Comment: Then maybe the switch needs a setting? Is it NC or NO?

Comment: It is NO, you have to set the state before simulating. But the switch is working 100%, because the LED otherhand is turning on/off like intended. It is just the bulb that makes problems - only in easyEDA

Comment: Use a resistor, see if that works. If it does then chances are that the bulb is fishy.

Comment: @a concerned citizen: have a look at the post. just changed the bulb with a resistor. Did i measured on the correct spot? I guess yes and "after the resistor that voltage" should be absolute correct, right?

Comment: Yes, it looks saturated, so the bulb should have lit up. The only other thing  can think of is that maybe the bulb, itself, has some settings, maybe it's set for 12 V, or 24 V, and it has a check for voltage. I don't know. But theevidence seems to point at the bulb (unless it's something else I have overlooked).

Comment: Yeah I setted it to 1 Watts at 5V so everything should have worked. I go with you that the bulb must be broken then. Specially when the same thing works on two other platforms. Thank you for having a look!

Answer (score 0):

Feeding more than one parallel base-emitter junction from a single resistor leaves the distribution of current to chance, variations in device and environmental parameters.

About 80 mA of base current is a bit high even for the 200 mA lamp - say 220 Ohms there, 2k2 for the "LED transistor".

The paranoid add a resistor from base to emitter - about 2 to 10 times "the base resistor" is a start.